# RPAREN error when compiling code

Tags: visual-studio, parsing

I am currently trying to build and conplie a code for my game inb UDK but i keep getting this error Parser: missing RPAREN at '{'

I have a copy of the code that is creating the problem located below.

```
{
    if (Stamina - StamJumpPenalty > 0 && super.DoJump(bUpdating)
        {
        Stamina -= StamJumpPenalty;
        return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

can some one please help me out, and maybe explain why this is happening please?

thanks guys

Comment: You seem to be missing a parenthesis for your if statement

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing parenthesis in the condition of the if statement.